# Disable magnifying glass in iOS html app

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to disable magnifying glass that appears when we long press on any element in iOS html application. I want to disable this magnifying glass from my whole application.

I have tried the following:

```
body, body * {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
    -webkit-user-callout: none !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
input, textarea {
    -webkit-user-select: text !important;
    user-select: text !important;
    -webkit-user-callout: default !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: default !important;
}
```

But it is not working. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157292/how-to-disable-the-magnifying-glass-in-uiwebview

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty I have also tried that solution and many other solutions related to css, but none has worked for me

Comment: Same issue... We even tried to disable it from XCode, no success... Invincible magnifier!