# How to disable magnifying glass in iPadOS15 safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, ios15

I want to disable text magnifying glass that appears when we long press on any html element.

It has started to appear again in IOS15.

I tried the following methods, but they did not work on iOS15.
[Disable magnifying glass in iOS html app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101308/disable-magnifying-glass-in-ios-html-app)

Do you know of any CSS properties or other ways to disable it?

Comment: Is there any way to suppress the magnifier without disabling the click event?

Comment: Or if you know the conditions of appearance, please let me know.

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Disabling text selection alone with `-webkit-user-select: none;` did not work for me. I must use **@Zhen Yao** approach with calling `event.preventDefault()` in the touchstart event too.

**Additionally:** You can disable the magnifying glass on the **entire document** or on a **specific element**, depending on which element you call the touchstart event and set the css.

```css
#some-html-id { -webkit-user-select: none; }
```

```js
/* disable on specific html element */
var htmlElement = document.getElementById( 'some-html-id' );

htmlElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function( event ) { 
      event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0efro6cw/

Answer (score 3):

The feature was brought back in iOS 15, see https://9to5mac.com/2021/06/07/ios-15-brings-back-the-magnifying-glass-for-accurate-text-selection/

One solution is to handle the `"touchstart"` event and call `event.preventDefault()` in your handler.

Note that the above solution does not work if you still want to handle events such as `"click"`.

Also, Apple fixes the issue in WebKit by allowing using `-webkit-user-select: none;` to disable magnifying glass, see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231161

Comment: I appreciate your response. By the way, one thing I would like to ask is that when I call ”event.preventDefault()” in ”touchstart”event, the subsequent ”click” event are disabled.
Do you know how to avoid this and at the same time disable the magnifier? I apologize for my poor English.

Comment: @TakabasiSyu In that case you can call `event.preventDefault()` within your original `click` event handler.

Comment: @ZhenYao It seems that calling preventDefault in click event handler does not prevent magnifying glass to display. I cannot find any way to disable magnifying glass, and at the same time still allow default behavior for click

Comment: This answer does not solve the issue.