# Avoid small rectangular magnifier to appear when tap and hold on webpage in safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, webkit

when I tap and hold on my web page, a small magnifier appears.
I need to avoid this, how we can do that?
I have added **-webkit-user-select: none** and **-webkit-touch-callout**: none in body tag as well, still when I tap and hold on screen a small rectangular magnifier appears.
I also added touchEvent listener on documentElement and called preventDefault in that event.

I started viewing this behaviour after upgrading my iOS device to 15 from 14

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491371/how-to-disable-magnifying-glass-in-ipados15-safari