# How to completely disable magnifying glass for UIWebView iOS9

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview, ios9

I've tried the following:

```
html, body, div, p, a, table, img
{
-webkit-user-select: none !important;
user-select: none !important;
-webkit-user-callout: none !important;
-webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
```

This works for my uiwebview that takes up the whole screen, but for my uiwebview that does not (adbannerview above), it pushes the magnifying glass above the uiwebview over the adbannerview.

Does anyone have any ideas that don't involve disabling  `UILongPressGestureRecognizers` on uiwebview's subviews as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157292/how-to-disable-the-magnifying-glass-in-uiwebview)?

Comment: @rmaddy, please read my question. It is not a duplicate of that question. I've tryied their solution and even put their solution in my question and explained what it does.

Comment: Same problem here, any solution plz?

Comment: @HassanTaleb None other than in the answer I posted in my question. As long as you don't mind disabling `UILongPressGestureRecognizers` on all the uiwebview subviews, then you've got a perfectly good solution. The answeree was concerned about Apple rejecting, which is always a concern. I don't think that will be an issue for them. But you never know.

Comment: I don't understand "uiwebview subviews", I tried to disable the UILongPressGestureRecognizers in the uiwebview , like this: `let LongTapWebVIew = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()` then: `func LongTapWebViewGesture(){
        LongTapWebVIew.addTarget(self, action: "tappedLongWebView")
        LongTapWebVIew.delegate = self
        WebView.addGestureRecognizer(LongTapWebVIew)
    }` then     `func tappedLongWebView() {
        LongTapWebVIew.enabled = false
    }` then call LongTapWebViewGesture() in viewDidLoad, but the magnifying glass still shown :/.. Can u give me some hint or code plz? @mark

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get suggested comments working by ensuring gestures are disabled after each page load.

So, in your webview delegate:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    disableLongPressGesturesForView(webView)
}
```

Then your function can look up each subview of the webview (and it's subview children), and disable any long press gestures.

```
func disableLongPressGesturesForView(view: UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let gestures = subview.gestureRecognizers as [UIGestureRecognizer]! {
            for gesture in gestures {
                if gesture is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
                    gesture.enabled = false
                }
            }
        }
        disableLongPressGesturesForView(subview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you look at my question here plz @rossbeale? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761868/how-can-we-disable-the-effect-of-enabled-bold-text-from-settings-in-the-iphone/32762352?noredirect=1#comment53389075_32762352

Answer (score 2):

I disabled the magnifying glass by iterating the subviews from the webview and finding which has UILongPressGestureRegonizer then disable it

Here is the snippet :

```
- (void)disableWebViewLongPressGestures:(UIWebView *)webview {
    for(id subView in webview.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subView;
            for(id ssView in scrollView.subviews) {
                if([NSStringFromClass([ssView class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebBrowserView"]) {
                    for(UIGestureRecognizer *gs in [ssView gestureRecognizers]) {
                        if ([gs isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
                        {
                            gs.enabled = NO;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```