# How can we disable the effect of enabled "bold text" from settings in the iphone (in my app)? - swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, ios9

If the user’s device has **bold text enabled** there are certain parts of the system that will automatically respond to that. For example, if you are using a **default navigation controller** in your app, **the title and the UIBarButtonItem at the top of the screen will become bold.**

How can I **disable** the effect of **bold text** to ***all my app*** and specially to the default navigation controller ( to the **title** and the **UIBarButtonItem** ) in my app ? - **swift 2.0** ( **iOS 8 & 9** ) . thx all : )

I have this code to detect if the bold text is enabled : (**if it is useful**)

```
 if (UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled()) { // use bold font 
       }
 else { 
    // use standard font
}
```

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Not yet @RoiMulia

Comment: I gave up on this as well haha. Just make sure the labels are breaking when the bold font is enabled

Answer (score 0):

If your Bar Button Item is using default(System) font, and if the user enable bold text, your screen text changes Bold. Customize font of your bar button item with regular text.

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 19) {     
    barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
}
```

Comment: I tried this code in AppDelegate: <br>
                if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 19) {
                    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font , NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red:0.959, green:0.959,blue:0.959,alpha:1.0)]
                }
<Br>
but this code change only the font of title , not the Bat Button Item !

Comment: Because you are changing title font here. Not bar button item font.
Try something like : if let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 19) {
    barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

Comment: I tried your code, but no result , still in bold :/

Comment: the problem is because I used : imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate) to change the tint color .. if I put "AlwaysOriginal" the bold is disabled but I can't do this because I want to set the tint color to the image by code @kiruthika selvavainayagam

Comment: the full code is: 
 let btn1Image = UIImage(named: "home");
        let tintedBtn1Image = btn1Image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        buttonTop1.setImage(tintedBtn1Image, forState: .Normal)
        buttonTop1.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0,blue:1.0,alpha:1.0)  // ~ White

Comment: Any further update in this, I still facing the same issue